# Erro ao fazer requisição post por conta do SerializerMethodField()

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Não consigo fazer um POST para criar um novo modelo no banco, única coisa que descobri é que o erro é por conta do SerializerMethodField(), ao desabilitar ele, consigo fazer o post tranquilo, porém, preciso dele para apresentar o nome do departamento por completo ao invés de somente o ID. Já procurei bastante na web mas não consegui achar uma maneira de resolver isso de forma clara.

models.py

```
class Departamento(models.Model):
    departamento = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.departamento


class Professor(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    departamento = models.ForeignKey('Departamento', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

viewsets.py

```
class ProfessorViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Professor.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfessorSerializer
```

serializers.py

```
class ProfessorSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    departamento = SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Professor
        fields = ('name','departamento')
    
    def get_departamento(self, obj):
        return "%s" %(obj.departamento)
```

Ao fazer um POST (utilizando o Postman, por exemplo), se eu desabilitar o SerializerMethodField() consigo criar um novo professor da seguinte forma:

```
{
    "name":"João",
    "departamento":"1" #supondo que tenho um departamento de ID=1 já cadastrado no banco
}
```

Mas já com o SerializerMethodField() ativado, não importa qual valor eu coloque lá, sempre apresenta o erro: NOT NULL constraint failed: professor_professor.departamento_id

Como consigo fazer o POST sem precisar retirar SMF()?

Comment: O seu json não deveria ser `{ "name": "Joao", "departamento": 1 }`? Pergunto isso, pois deveria ser o id e não a string. Pelo seu modelo, não definindo id, ele é inteiro.

Comment: Sim, mas isso é quando não estou utilizado o SMF(), o que quero saber é como enviar o JSON utilizando o SMF()

Comment: Entendi... acho que seu serializer está errado. Veja [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17280007/retrieving-a-foreign-key-value-with-django-rest-framework-serializers)

Comment: Acredito que não, acompanhei esta parte de um tutorial. E funciona normalmente para o método GET, só ao fazer um POST que não funciona, pois ele pede algum valor que não consigo saber qual é - e não é o ID ou o nome por extenso em formato de string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O [SerializerMethodField serve apenas para leitura](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield). Eu acredito que a melhor forma de resolver isso é fazendo com que `departamento` fosse também um serializer.
Você pode reescrever o método `create()` e `update()` do `ProfessorSerializer` para apenas buscar o departamento pelo ID.

```py
class DepartamentoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = ["id", "nome"]
        extra_kwargs = {
            "nome": {'read_only': True},
        }

class ProfessorSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    departamento = DepartamentoSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Professor
        fields = ('name', 'departamento')
   
    def create(self, validated_data):
        departamento_data = validated_data.pop("departamento")
        professor = Professor(**validated_data)
        professor.departamento_id = departamento_data["id"]
        professor.save()
        return professor
```

e assim você poderia enviar e receber tanto o ID quanto o nome em seus requests:

POST:

```js
{
    "name":"João",
    "departamento": {"id": 1}
}
```

GET:

```js
{
    "name":"João",
    "departamento": {
        "id": 1,
        "nome": "Financeiro"
    }
}
```

Você pode [ver aqui](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#writable-nested-representations) como atualizar ou criar objetos utilizando serializers dentro de serializers.